# oracle -PL/SQL Resolving variable names in a filename declaration

Tags: variables, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm trying to read in a series of template files on my local machine and put the data into a clob column in an oracle database.  I have something that works really well when the filename is hardwired:

```
Declare
    v_Template clob:= '
     @@MyFolder\MyFilename.txt
     '; 

    Begin
    --Insert the contents of the file into a Clob column in the database
    end;
    /
```

This variable value is later inserted into a CLOB column of a table.

It is described here.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGjI7i24fXAhXhx1QKHQ14AcoQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19721274%2Fcan-sqlplus-read-the-contents-of-a-file-into-a-variable&usg=AOvVaw3qxvCpXHc9D2tof3Gisvlz

But when I try to put a variable for the filename, The value of v_template gets populated with the name of the variable, not the contents of the file.  Is there some way to get this to resolve properly? For example,

```
DECLARE
-- the @@ expression must be in separate line as follows

Myfilename varchar(50):='@@MyPath\Template_File.txt';

file_contents VARCHAR2(32767):='
 &&MyFileName
 ';
Begin
insert into MyTAble (template_definition)
values(file_contents);
commit;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the double-at-sign on a line by itself like in your first example.

```
set serveroutput on

Declare
file_contents VARCHAR2(32767) := '
@@c:\temp\efs.txt
';   
BEGIN 
  dbms_output.put_line('===');
  dbms_output.put_line(file_contents);
  dbms_output.put_line('===');
END;
/
===

this is
a test

===

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the && did not work.  The value  '&&MyFileName' gets inserted into the table instead of the contents of the file that is defined by the MyFileName variable.  If I remove 'set define off', I get prompted for the value of MyFileName. 
 
The point of this is to have the filename be a variable so I can read the contents of a directory and loop through a list of files. I edited the second block of code to match your suggestion.

Comment: My answer involved double-at-signs.  I typed "ampersand" when I meant "at-sign".  Are you trying to prompt for the filename? I'll correct my typo in the meantime.

Comment: I don't want to prompt for a filename.  I want to use a variable for the filename (MyFileName) and then read the contents of that file into another variable (File_Contents).  Your example above hard codes the file name, which works very well.  But I can't get it to work when it is @@MyFileNameVariable.  It either won't read it, or it populates the File_Contents variable with the name of the file instead of the contents of the file. Thanks so much for looking into this.